Linux fedora boot option won't appear on grub boot menu after new fedora (additional) instalation
Recently I had my fedora (39) running ok, every time I booted the pc grub boot menu jumped in asking which distro I wanted to run. Everything ok.
Then I created a new disk partition and installed a new fedora (40) in that partition. Now when in the boot grub menu; only the new fedora installation appears, but NOT my old installation.
So basically I've lost access to my old fedora with all my system modifications and files. (I created the new partition in order to test a backup system, to avoid precisely things like this in the future :P )
This is a Gparted capture, here you can see a windows installation, the old fedora 39 installation which I want to recover access to (big partition, /dev/nvme0n1p7); and the new fedora 40, which is booting fine (/dev/nvme0n1p9)
Gparted capture
old fedora partitions: nvme0n1p6 (boot) nvme0n1p7 (/, /home)
new fedora partitions: nvme0n1p8 (/boot) nvme0n1p9 (/, /home)
fdisk output
ggk2@fedora:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for ggk2: 
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: KBG50ZNV512G KIOXIA                     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2A5D2F9C-1607-4617-A329-2D22974A99A3

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    534528     796671    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    796672  307996671 307200000 146.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 307996672  314392575   6395904     3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5 998117376 1000214527   2097152     1G Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p6 314392576  316489727   2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p7 316489728  878151679 561661952 267.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p8 878151680  880248831   2097152     1G Linux extended boot
/dev/nvme0n1p9 880248832  998117375 117868544  56.2G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/zram0: 8 GiB, 8589934592 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

one thing I've noticed here is that apparently each fedora installation as a boot partition, both have the same file system (etx4) but in the case of the new fedora the the type of this partition is different from the old ( Linux filesystem VS Linux extended boot)
Non standard file structure ?
something interesting is that recently I've been trying several backup-snapshot solutions and I believe that some of them modified the / directory. So in / instead of having root directories like /etc or /bin it has only 4 directories!:
ggk2@fedora:~$ ls -l /mnt/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   6 Jul 15 09:37 boot
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   6 Feb  2 03:57 home
dr-xr-xr-x. 1 root root 176 Jul 14 17:48 root
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 210 Jul  5 22:04 timeshift


ll  /mnt/root/
total 24
dr-xr-xr-x. 1 root root    0 Jul 21  2023 afs
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    7 Jul 21  2023 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1220 Jul 14 21:38 boot
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    0 Feb  2 09:36 dev
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 5222 Jul 15 18:17 etc
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    0 Feb  2 09:36 home
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    7 Jul 21  2023 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    9 Jul 21  2023 lib64 -> usr/lib64
drwx------. 1 root root    0 Nov  1  2023 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    0 Jul 21  2023 media
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    6 Jul  8 21:02 mnt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   98 Feb 12 17:06 npmrc
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   82 May 28 14:18 opt
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    0 Feb  2 09:36 proc
dr-xr-x---. 1 root root  256 Jul 13 20:17 root
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    0 Feb  2 09:36 run
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    8 Jul 21  2023 sbin -> usr/sbin
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   19 May 30 16:31 snap -> /var/lib/snapd/snap
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    0 Jul 21  2023 srv
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    0 Feb  2 09:36 sys
drwxrwxrwt. 1 root root    0 Jul 15 18:17 tmp
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  168 Nov  1  2023 usr
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  208 May 30 16:31 var

I believe this odd file structure may be because of a configuration in timeshift, where at the beginning I kept the timeshift snapshots in the same disk. Therefore it seems timeshift may have did this ?
The thing is, that this didn't matter before, because the system was booting well until I've installed the new fedora.
fstab files
old fedora fstab
ggk2@fedora:~$ cat /mnt/root/etc/fstab

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Fri Feb  2 03:39:07 2024
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk/'.
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info.
#
# After editing this file, run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to update systemd
# units generated from this file.
#
UUID=e3a68aed-3eac-45de-b3f0-2b71f0022b95 /root                       btrfs   subvol=/root,compress=zstd:1 0 0
UUID=a20d77d0-2028-4f18-95fc-e9c504c1216a /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=E023-29BC          /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 2
UUID=e3a68aed-3eac-45de-b3f0-2b71f0022b95 /home                   btrfs   subvol=/home,compress=zstd:1 0 0

new fedora fstab
ggk2@fedora:/$ sudo cat /etc/fstab 
[sudo] password for ggk2: 

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Sun Jul 14 09:19:09 2024
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk/'.
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info.
#
# After editing this file, run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to update systemd
# units generated from this file.
#
UUID=23bccc39-c63f-4e2b-abbe-c25d7d0f0d2c /                       btrfs   subvol=root00,compress=zstd:1 0 0
UUID=348cd8a3-9759-4224-8544-9a056b1d2c4a /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=E023-29BC          /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 2
UUID=23bccc39-c63f-4e2b-abbe-c25d7d0f0d2c /home                   btrfs   subvol=home00,compress=zstd:1 0 0

What I tried until now
I have followed these tutorials, similar idea but slightly different approach: https://thomas-leister.de/en/repair-fedora-efi-bootloader/ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FIAxzzE45Sg
The solutions proposed here are to reinstall grub and shim in the old fedora. Tried but didn't work. In the last step I get this error
root@fedora:/home/ggk2# grub2-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi /dev/nvme0n1
grub2-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.

I created a bootable USB and did the operation from there, now I'm using the new fedora installation for these operations.
I also tried to regenerate the grub configuration file, it detects my old partition! (Fedora Linux 39 at /dev/nvme0n1p7), but then when I reboot everything stays the same :( ?
root@fedora:/home/ggk2# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Fedora Linux 39 (Workstation Edition) on /dev/nvme0n1p7
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done

Now I'm going to try to add a new entry to the grub stub using efibootmgr
Meanwhile, any help will be VERY appreciated, I've been trying to fix this for 3 straight days :P
